# Android app says folder exists but I cant see it

Tags: android, windows

I have an app I made on my old phone. It creates a folder called LocationTracker. When Im stepping through the code it says the folder exists. But I cant seem to browse to it when I connect my phone to the computer. I just checked my file explorer on my phone and i can browse to the folder there as well. According to that it is under the sd card, but i just cant see it on my PC.

Im rooting around in my file explorer on my phone. There appears to be 2 sd card folders. One is called sdcard1, and that seems to be my actual sd card. The other is called sd card. I think its an emulated one. I use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), i thought that returned the sd card if one was available. If that is the case why is it using the emulated folder instead of the actual sd card folder? How do I fix this?

Comment: What is the absolute path of the folder? By default folders are created in application data directory in `/data/data/AppId` which is (without root) not accessible by anyone else than the application.

Comment: The path when debugging is: /storage/emulated/0/LocationTracker/ErrorLogMap.txt

Answer (score 0):

From [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()):

> In devices with multiple "external" storage directories, this directory represents the "primary" external storage that the user will interact with. Access to secondary storage is available through

The rest of the sentence is sadly missing. However the methods are `Context.getExternalFilesDirs()` and `Context.getExternalMediaDirs()`.